# MYSQL - UPDATE a dos tablas

Tags: mysql, vb.net

hola amigos(as) junto con saludarlos venia a pedir su orientación (nuevamente), Tengo 2 tablas que tienen en común un campo: id_estado. Lo que tengo que hacer es actualizar ese campo en ambas tabla de forma simultanea, ya que este id luego muestra el campo en un grilla.
Mi problema viene con la sentencia en si, y con las condiciones para que el update se realize, las tablas son asi:

```html
/*Tabla Acciones*/  
  id_accion (ai)(pk)
  id_incidencia (int)
  id_estado(int)
  detalle(varchar)
  
  
  /*Tabla incidencias*/  
  id_incidencia(ai)(pk)
  id_estado(int)
  id_funcionario (int)
  detalle(varchar)
```

como veran, a una incidencia se le pueden insertar multiples acciones, por lo cual requiero hacer:
.- update al campo id_estado de la tabla incidencias, segun el id_incidencia, pero que tambien se filtre a que id_accion pertenece, sera posible? utilize esta query en forma de prueba, no me dio error, y modifico en principio, pero ahora no funciona mas:

```
UPDATE tbl_acciones_incidencia, tbl_incidencias
```

SET
id_estado ='9',
id_estado='9'
FROM tbl_acciones_incidencia ac, tbl_incidencias inc
ON ac.id_estado=inc.id_estado
WHERE id_incidencia='3'

Agradezco a todos desde ya sus comentarios y ayuda

Comment: Puedes utilizar triggers, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: hola estimado gracias por tu tiempo,, leyendo la docu, y algun ejemplo, llegue a que este podria ser mi trigger: CREATE TRIGGER actualizarEstadoTablaIncidencias AFTER UPDATE
ON tbl_acciones_incidencia
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE tbl_incidencias SET id_estado= NEW.id_estado WHERE id_estado=NEW.id_estado , el tema es que lo ejecuto, hago un cambio en la tabla tbl_acciones_incidencia, pero no se cambia nada en la tabla tbl_incidencias